# How to use SET list variable in CASE statement in HIVE

Tags: select, hive, set, case

I am coming across an issue where I set a list of value into a variable and then I want to use that list in my CASE statement in the SELECT statement but for some reason, I keep on getting an error.

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:38 cannot recognize input near 'IN' 'THEN' ''C'' in expression specification

For instance

```
SET close=('a','b','c');
SET open=('x','y','z');
SELECT *,
      CASE 
      WHEN test IN ${close} then 'c'
      WHEN test IN ${open} then 'o' 
      END as case
FROM t1
```

I am wondering if it is even possible to use this logic in a HIVE query.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are defining the variable in a correct way, however they we you are referring back is not correct and that's why the error. you need to refer variable using `${hiveconf:vairable_name}`

try this

```
SET close=('a','b','c');
SET open=('x','y','z');
SELECT *,
      CASE 
      WHEN test IN ${hiveconf:close} then 'c'
      WHEN test IN ${hiveconf:open} then 'o' 
      END as case
FROM t1
```

**Long Explanation:**

There are total three `namespaces` available for holding variables.

1. **hiveconf** - hive started with this, all the hive configuration is stored as part of this conf. initially variable substitution was not part of hive and when it got introduced, all the user defined variables were stored as part of this as well. Which definitely is not a good idea.  So two more namespaces are created.
2. **hivevar**: To store user variables
3. **system**: To store system variables.

**And this is how it works.**

**hiveconf** is still the **default namespace**, so if you don't provide any namespace it will store your variable in hiveconf namespace.

However, When it comes to referring a variable, it's not true. By default it refers to **hivevar** namespace. confusing, right?  it would be more clear from following example.

no namespace provided, variable `var` will be stored in `hiveconf` namespace.

```
set var="default_namespace";
```

This will work, as you have specified `hiveconf` namespace

```
select ${hiveconf:var};
```

This will give you error as, if namespace is not provided it checks in `hivevar` namespace. And in `hivevar` there is no variable with name `var`

```
select ${var};
```

we have explicitly provided `hivevar` namespace

```
set hivevar:var="hivevar_namespace";
```

as we are providing the namespace this will work.

```
select ${hivevar:var};
```

And as default workspace used during refering a variable is `hivevar`, following will work too.

```
select ${var};
```

Comment: It looks like it is working. Thank you so much!!!! May I ask why is this 'hiveconf:' necessary when you are referencing to the variable in the query?

Comment: for your use case it makes sense to use `hivevar` namespace.

Comment: Nice explanation. +1

Comment: @GaurangShah  This helps me a lot understand how to write better code in the future. Thanks a lot